# How to select a rect area and paste a single string

Tags: vim

I would like to replace a rectangular area with a yanked single string (as opposed to another rect area).

For example, yank the string "foobar", select the numeric characters of the following table and paste the string over the rectangular region.

```
poum 123 pam
poum 456 pam
poum 789 pam
```

Which would yield this output:

```
poum foobar pam
poum foobar pam
poum foobar pam
```

BBedit has this capability and I find it quite handy. The only way I found to do this with Vi is to yank the string into a given register (say register "a"), select the region, delete it, reselect it using <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, and finally paste the string using  <kbd>I</kbd>   <kbd>ctrl</kbd> –<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>esc</kbd> .

I am looking for a simpler way to do this. E.g. select the region, paste the string. It should be as simple as pasting a rect area to another rect area (an operation described here: [Vim: how to select a rect area and do copy/paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974894/vim-how-to-select-a-rect-area-and-do-copy-paste)).

Comment: Can you add an example of the result that you expect after your paste?

Comment: Here you go. Please note I also corrected a typo that might have confused you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yank the string you want to paste. Select the area you want to replace (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>). Press <kbd>c</kbd> to cut the area out and go into insert mode, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> then <kbd>0</kbd> (zero) to paste the contents of register 0 (since the text you cut went into `"`) and finally <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave insert mode. Or yank into a particular register explicitly (<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>) and paste from that one (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>).

Comment: Thank you. I haven't used 'c' yet so I did'nt try this one. I guess your solution is as simple as it can get.

Comment: Always more to learn in vim. Since you haven't used `c`, you may want to look at `C`,`s`, and `S` too. All quite useful, e.g. I use `ciw` and `ci(` quite often.